# ie11 Detecting Enter Key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code in an asp mvc page

```
 $('#regForm').submit(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == '13') {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

The aim is to prevent the form from submitting when enter is pressed.

We have noticed that in ie 11, this is not working, and on stepping into the code via debug, `event.keycode` is `null`. I have been doing some researching on this, and it seems to be an issue because we have the IE-8 Compatibility Meta Tag present on the page, which means that `event.keyCode` (and `event.which`) returns `undefined` for the event, and so my form is always submitted.

So how do I rewrite this to get round the issue?

Comment: Can you remove the IE-8 Compatibility Meta Tag and see if it works?

Comment: why not just bind `click` on the submit button ?

Comment: @Hacketo because form might be submitted from keyboard, too?

Comment: @cyberskunk "The aim is to prevent the form from submitting when enter is pressed" I don't know any other key that fire a submit of a form.

Comment: @Hacketo But how `click` is related to pressing `Enter`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the keypress event, not form submit

```
$('#regForm').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`type="button"`** attribute with `<button>` element
So that **IE** thinks the button as a simple button instead of a submit button.

So form will not submit

You can also get more details from below url

http://tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/

Comment: Unforntunately, its a text box that people are pressing enter on, so that won't work. (My bad for not stating this in my original question)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, use window.event:

```
 $('#regForm').submit(function (e) {
     var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

                if (keyCode == '13') {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, I found a similar solution on S.O. earlier, but I was still getting null.

Comment: @Matt Ok, was convinced that it should work. I see you found your solution anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#regForm').keypress((event) => {
   if (event.key === "Enter") {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```